# Encoding servlets with UTF-8 on WildFly

Tags: servlets, encoding, utf-8, wildfly

I used to run my JavaEE applications on GlassFish server, and there was no problem with the encoding type (UTF-8) since I added the following property in JVM Settings of the server:

```
file.encoding = UTF-8
```

Now, I'm using WildFly server instead, and I've done the supposed configuration to set the encoding type into UTF-8 but characters are still appearing with wrong encoding not only on the web page but also while debugging the application with Eclipse, the response data loaded using (web servlet requests) are not UTF-8 encoded.
Below is what I did on WildFly:

[snapshot1](https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-872143-22902/en5.bmp)

[snapshot2](https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-872143-22903/en2.bmp)

Comment: Please accept answer from @user158037. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Wildfly now uses Undertow, so check for that subsystem in you configuration file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
      <server name="default-server">
         <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" url-charset="UTF-8" />
      </server>
      <servlet-container default-encoding="UTF-8" name="default">
         <jsp-config />
         <websockets />
      </servlet-container>
   </subsystem>
```

With `url-charset` and `default-encoding` set there is no need for filter.

Answer (score -4):

Use a CharacterEncodingFilter (like this one, taken from Spring) to force UTF-8 as the encoding of all requests and responses:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private String encoding;

    private boolean forceEncoding;

    @Override
    public final void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String encod = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
        if(encod !=null){
            encoding = encod ;
        }
        String forceEncod = filterConfig.getInitParameter("forceEncoding");
        if(forceEncod !=null){
            forceEncoding = forceEncod ;
        }
    }

    public final void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (this.encoding != null && (this.forceEncoding || request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(this.encoding);
            if (this.forceEncoding) {
                response.setCharacterEncoding(this.encoding);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Enforce UTF-8 Character Encoding -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>somepackages.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: Even Using a character encoding filter did not solve the problem!